# How to use webcam in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, camera

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I want to add a webcam test for Chrome OS devices, and I'm having trouble my script to run properly. I have followed the documentation and examples, but the it doesn't seem to execute correctly.

Here are the details of my setup:

I have a manifest.json file with the following relevant configuration:

```
  {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_URLs>"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"],
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a contentScript.js file located in the same directory as the manifest.json file. The file contains some basic code for testing:

```
// contentScript.js

// Inject an iframe into the current tab's page
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("iframe.html");
iframe.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// Listen for messages from the iframe
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data.type === "mediaAccessSuccess") {
    // Notify the background script about the successful access
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "requestMediaAccess" });
  } else if (event.data.type === "mediaAccessError") {
    // Notify the background script about the failed access
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "requestMediaAccessError", error: event.data.error });
  }
});
```

Here is my iframe.html:

```
<!-- iframe.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Request media access in the iframe
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(() => {
          // Notify the parent content script about the successful access
          window.parent.postMessage({ type: "mediaAccessSuccess" }, "*");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Notify the parent content script about the failed access
          window.parent.postMessage({ type: "mediaAccessError", error: error.message }, "*");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My background.js:

```
// background.js

// Listen for messages from content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.type === "requestMediaAccess") {
    // Request media access from the background script
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
        function: requestMediaAccessInTab,
      });
    });
  }
});

// Function to request media access in the tab
function requestMediaAccessInTab() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(() => {
      // Notify the content script about the successful access
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "mediaAccessSuccess" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Notify the content script about the failed access
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "mediaAccessError", error: error.message });
    });
}
```

And finally my popup.js:

```
// popup.js

// Send a message to the content script to toggle the webcam
function toggleWebcam() {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    const activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
      function: toggleWebcamInTab,
    });
  });
}

// Function to toggle the webcam in the tab
function toggleWebcamInTab() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "toggleWebcam" });
}

// Attach event listener to the button
document.getElementById("toggleWebcamButton").addEventListener("click", toggleWebcam);
```

I want to be able to press the button in my popup.html

```
<button id="toggleWebcamButton">Toggle Webcam</button>
```

There always seems to be a lot of issues with this. Sorry for a lot of code, but any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Was this ever solved?